# Is there a way to shift bits between two contiguous memory spaces in C?

Tags: c, bit, shift

I'm trying to retrieve the bits lost after shifting an integer with the "<<" operator, so i created a int pointer "b" which i initialized with full 1. And on the left of the adress b i created an int "a" which i initialized at 0. Then, i perfomed a left shift of "*b" and checked the value of a which didn't change, so is it possible to REALLY shift bits on continuous memory spaces ?

Here is my code:

```
    int main(){

    int a=0;

    int *b;

    b = &a + 1;

    *b=0xffffffff;

    *b<<2;

    printf("%d\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior. It's not clear what you want to do here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I want to create two int on a contiguous space of memory, and shift bits from one int to the other.

Comment: Lost bits are lost -- they aren't moved to adjacent memory (doing so would trash that memory). Some operations are irreversible. Keep a copy of the original if you need it later. You can of course determine which bits will be lost in a shift and use bit operations to move those bits somewhere else -- but the shift operator doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: @iharob `b = &a + 1;` is legal. It's a "one past the end" pointer. However , trying to write to the location `*b` causes UB.

Comment: @M.M yes you are 100% right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just do the reverse of the shift before shifting. example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int lshift(int var,int nbits, int *lost){
    if(lost)
        *lost=var>>((sizeof(int)*8)-nbits);
    return var<<nbits;
}

int main() {

    int n=0xffffdd, // variable n
        l,          // l for lost
        v;          // v for result

    v=lshift(n,16,&l);
    printf( "var n\t= %08X\n"
            "result\t= %08X\n"
            "lost\t= %08X\n",
            n,v,l); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply test the MSbit of the lower memory operand and set a flag, then shift both integers then or the upper int with 1 if flag set:
bool flag

```
int i[2];    //This should guarantee the correct order of int's
....
flag = i[0] & 0x10000000;    //Assume integer to be 32 bits
i[0] <<= 1;
i[1] <<= 1;
if (flag)
    i[1] |= 1;
```

The following code works for any memory int contiguous or not contiguous. The code uses pointers to 'sort' the addresses:

```
#define pMin(x, y) (x)<(y)?(x):(y)
#define pMax(x, y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)

int main(void)
{
    int flag;
    unsigned a, b;
    unsigned *p1, *p2;

    p1 = pMin(&a, &b);
    p2 = pMax(&a, &b);

    printf("&a = %p\n", &a);
    printf("&b = %p\n", &b);
    printf("p1 = %p\n", p1);
    printf("p2 = %p\n", p2);

    *p1 = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<64; i++)
    {
        flag = *p1 & 0x80000000;
        printf ("%03d) flag=%5.5s, Value=%08x%08x\n", i, flag?"true":"false", *p2, *p1);
        *p1 <<= 1;
        *p2 <<= 1;
        if (flag)
            *p2 |= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note the 2 macros `pMin` and `pMax` to sort the addresses.

Comment: Thanks frankie, but if i1 is on the left of i2, are you sure i should not check the LSbit instead ?

Comment: I misundestood your previous comment. You mean if positions are reversed? This depends on how you allocated them. Normally a compiler allocate space sequencially, so `i2`should follow  `i1`. A safer way to allocate the two integers could be using an array (see updated answer).

Comment: Ok Frankie, here is the code i wrote inspired from yours but it does not print "true"...                                                                                                                   
       int main(){

 int flag;

 int a,b;

 b = 0xffffffff;


 printf("%p\n",&a);

 printf("%p\n",&b);


 flag = a & 0x10000000;

 b <<= 1;

 if (flag)
  printf("true\n");

 return 0;
    }[link]

Comment: Your code make absolutely nosense. Why you print address of variables? You test `a` variable for high bit set, but you have never initialized `a`. Then why it should be `true`? Again what you really want to do? Please rephrase your question, let apart the code, and try to explain clearly what you want to do.

Comment: I printed adresses of variables to check if they were contiguous, i thought that when declaring a variable it automatically sets it to 0, It should print true if the value of "flag" is 1 e.g if a bit with value one was actually shifted from b to a . Again, i simply want to put all (or some) of the "1" bits of "b" in "a"...